# JQuery .get() to call http handler - doesn't return expected result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, httphandler

I originally had the function below called 'g.initWithUserGeolocation' working successfully.  It's a JQuery .get() that calls an http handler that should return a JSON object, and the Latitude and Longitude properties of that object are then assigned to a couple of other properties

```
var GMAPS = function (mapHeight, serviceMethodName) {

var g = {}

//center location
g.currentLat = 0;
g.currentLng = 0;


g.initWithUserGeolocation = function () {

    var url = "http://www.lesmills.dev/sites/main/classlocator/handler/UserLocation.ashx";
    $.get(url, {}, function (data) {
        g.currentLat = data.Latitude;
        g.currentLng = data.Longitude;
    });

    setTimeout(function () { map.init(); }, 1000);
}

g.init = function () {

    var self = this;

    //Check if coordinates have been set
    if (this.currentLat == 0 || this.currentLng == 0) {
        this.initWithUserGeolocation();
        //setTimeout(function () { map.init(); }, 1000);
    }
```

When I debug the http handler using Visual Studio, at the point it's called by the JQuery .get(), it successfully picks up the user's location based on their IP, and writes the JSON that encapsulates this info to the response, like this:

```
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var user = new CurrentUser();
        user.Location = MyService.GetLocation(ipAddress));

        var result = Util.ToJson(user.Location);

        context.Response.Write(result);
```

This object that is returned contains the correct longitude and latitude for the user's location. However, using Firebug, when I put a breakpoint in the 'success' callback function of the above JQuery .get(), on the line

```
g.currentLat = data.Latitude;
```

, the breakpoint isn't hit, as if the .get() hasn't been successful.  Later down in the g.init function, this.currentLat and this.currentLng are both zero.

As I say, this was previously working.  The code hasn't changed.  Previously however, the JQuery code and the handler code were based in the same Visual Studio project deployed to a site with hostname www.lesmills.dev and the handler was called from the JQuery .get() using a relative url.  Now, I've moved the JQuery code into a site that has the hostname m.lesmills.dev, and the handler is being called using an absolute URL to it's original location in the www.lesmills.dev website.  Why is the JQuery code not receiving the correct co-ordinates from the http handler?

Comment: Can't use AJAX/JSON across domains... will need JSONP. [This will probably help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3964961/1810243)

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the 'NET' tab of Firebug and looked up the request to the ashx handler, I saw that the GET was successful (response code 200), however the 'response' shown in the 'NET' tab was blank.  So basically I can request to a different subdomain, however the response won't be returned to me.  When I move the handler to the same subdomain, I get a successful JSON response.  The follwoing question (pointed out by MikeSmithDev) has details of the cross-domain (including cross-subdomain) limitations of JQuery .get(), which is essentially an AJAX/JSON request.

[Is there any way to load json from a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964835/is-there-any-way-to-load-json-from-a-subdomain/3964961#3964961)